# Pseudo ::before ::after inline heading on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, pseudo-element

I have some heading with following pseudo style below

```
h2 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
} 

h2::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 1px;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    top: 50%;
}

h2::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    left: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

It looks fine in Firefox, the pseudo element will remain right after the first line of h1 text.

The problem came up when I tested in Chrome responsive mode on small screen below 500px. `display:inline` seems not working.

[image]

Any workaround to make Chrome displaying my pseudo like in firefox?

Answer (score 1):

> First of all check this code, this works perfectly same in both
>   browsers,

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

h2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
}

h2::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 1px;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  top: 14px;
}

h2::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 14px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eiusmod tempor </h2>

<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br> eiusmod tempor </h2>

<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br> eiusmod tempor <br> eiusmod tempor</h2>
```

**The bug was `display: inline;` is detected in both browsers in two different ways.**

*Sample Images Chrome:*
[image]

*Sample Images Firefox:*
[image]

*this caused the **`::before` & `::after`** to change there position in both browsers.*

I solved it by changing the `display: inline;` to  `display: inline-block;`, hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: hi @weBBer thanks for the answer, I need the line to stick right after the first line of text (when the text divide in some lines on small screen) the problem is  `inline-block` will not achieve that,

Comment: :)  I'm not sure if we're on the same page. take a look at my screenshot (Firefox) what I need is the same like that

Comment: @YudyAnanda updated my code, Check it one more time.

Comment: Ok, it works but since I'm not use the `<br>` (the heading is for generated blogpost content) so when the heading break into several line (on small screen) the pseudo will treat the heading as a block again and the pseudo will move away from the first line of the heading.  but thank you anyway